# xmlseealso equivalent in Simplexml

Tags: jaxb, simplexml

what is the equivalent for **@xmlseealso** jaxb in **simplexml** . The response Iam parsing looks like this :

```
<things xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="thing">
    <val>185</val>
</things>
<things xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="thing">
    <val>162</val>
</things>
```

I am looking for a response mapping like this

```
Response.java

@ElementList
List<Object> things;

Thing.java

@Element
int val;
```

How can I dynamically map 'things' to a list of 'thing' as I would do in jaxb using xmlseealso . Is there a way in Simplexml ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean matching a list of elements of different classes but with a shared superclass, then the solution is the @ElementListUnion annotation. Your

```
@XmlSeeAlso({X.class, Y.class, Z.class})
```

should be represented as:

```
@ElementListUnion({
   @ElementList(entry="x", inline=true, type=X.class),
   @ElementList(entry="y", inline=true, type=Y.class),
   @ElementList(entry="z", inline=true, type=Z.class)               
})
private List<Superclass> xyz;
```

see http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementListUnion.html